# Given a continuous function such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} |f(x)| = 1$, prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$ or $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -1$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous functions in $\mathbb R$ so that $\lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x)|=1$.  Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$ or $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-1$.

Hint: First, prove that $\exists N>0~\forall x>N,f(x)\neq 0$

Tried all kind of things, with $M-\varepsilon$ definition, but haven't managed to figure this one out.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can't you just use the fact that
$$\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=|\lim_{x\to a}f(x)|$$
?

Comment: @Nilknarf: No since $a=\infty $ in the OP question.

Comment: @Surb Aw, shucks. :P

Comment: Given the hint: suppose that the statement isn't true. Then the function must be in the neighborhood of both -1 and +1 'arbitrarily often' as $x\to\infty$.  Can you say anything about its behavior in between those?

Comment: @Nilknarf That holds provided $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists, which is what the OP has to prove.

Comment: @Nilknarf: your idea is correct, but as egreg pointed out you need existence of the limit and that is where continuity of $f$ plays a role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By hypothesis, there is $M$ such that $\lvert f([M,+\infty))\rvert\subseteq \left(\frac12,\frac32\right)$. Equivalently, $$f([M,+\infty))\subseteq \left(-\frac32,-\frac12\right)\cup\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)$$

By the intermediate value theorem, the image of an interval under a continuous map is an interval. Therefore either $f([M,+\infty))\subseteq \left(-\frac32,-\frac12\right)$ or $f([M,+\infty))\subseteq \left(\frac12,\frac32\right)$.

In the first case, $1=\lim_{x\to\infty} \lvert f(x)\rvert=\lim_{x\to\infty}-f(x)$. In the second case, $1=\lim_{x\to\infty} \lvert f(x)\rvert=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the hint, i.e. there is some $N$ such that when $x > N$, we have $f(x) \neq 0$. From this we can prove that either $f(x) < 0$ or $f(x) > 0$ when $x > N$; suppose not, then there are $x, y > N$ such that $f(x) < 0 < f(y)$, and by the intermediate value theorem, there would be some $z$ between $x$ and $y$ such that $f(z) = 0$.

Assume without loss of generality that $f(x) > 0$ for $x > N$.
The only candidate for the limit is 1, and I think the argument can be finished from here easily.

Answer (score 0):

For any $\epsilon >0$ there is $M>0$ such that $\left||f(x)|-1\right|<\epsilon$

Suppose $f(x)>0$.
We have $|f(x)|=f(x)$ so $\left|f(x)-1\right|<\epsilon$ so $\lim_{x\to \infty } \, f(x)=1$

If $f(x)<0$ then $|f(x)|=-f(x)$ and we have $\left|-f(x)-1\right|<\epsilon$ which is $\left|f(x)+1\right|<\epsilon$ which means $\left|f(x)-(-1)\right|<\epsilon$ or, in other words, $\lim_{x\to \infty } \, f(x)=-1$.

Comment: What? The conclusions about $\lim$ are incorrect. How can you deduce from either $f(x)>0$ or not that $\lim f(x)=1$? You didn't even use continuity of $f$ and the statement clearly fails for discontinous $f$.

Comment: I think you mean "suppose $f(x) > 0$ for $x$ bigger than some $N$". If that's the case, then you have not proved why there are no other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If the limit exist, it must be $\pm 1$ (why). So let prove that it doesn't exist. The only case we have to consider is if there are $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ s.t. $x_n,y_n\to \infty $ and $$\lim_{n\to \infty }f(x_n)=-1\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{n\to \infty }f(y_n)=1.$$
I let you argument why. And this will give you a contradiction with the continuity of $f$. Indeed, using intermediate value theorem, you will be able to construct a sequence $(z_n)$ s.t. $f(z_n)=0$ for all $n\geq N$ from a certain rank $N$. And this will contradict $\lim_{n\to \infty }|f(z_n)|=1.$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there exists $k$ such that, for $x>k$, $|f(x)|>0$ (prove it).

I claim that there exists $M$ such that, for $x\ge M$, $f(x)$ has the same sign as $f(M)$.

If $Z(f)$ is not empty, let $M'=\sup Z(f)$. Note that $Z(f)$ is bounded above by $k$, so $M'\le k$. Define $M=M'+1$; then $M\notin Z(f)$ and so $f(M)\ne0$.

If $f(M)>0$, then $f(x)>0$, for every $x>M$. Otherwise there would exist $x_0>M$ with $f(x_0)=0$, by the intermediate value theorem, which is a contradiction to $M>M'$.

Similarly, if $f(M)<0$, then $f(x)<0$, for every $x>M$.

Now conclude using the fact that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x)|=
\lim_{\substack{x\to\infty\\x>M}}|f(x)|
$$

There is also the case $Z(f)=\emptyset$ to take care of, but it's easy (again by the intermediate value theorem).